# Next JS - how to give object a unique id?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to give my object a unique id by using Math.random, but I am getting the error below. If I change the Math.random to a integer like 4, the error goes away but I need the id to be unique.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

```
const data = [
    {
        id: Math.random(),
        sentence: 'hello there',
    },
    {
        id: Math.random(),
        sentence: 'bye!',
    },
]

export default function Index(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{data[0].id}</h1>
            <h1>{data[0].sentence}</h1>
            <h1>{data[1].id}</h1>
            <h1>{data[1].sentence}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Q: Please show us the part of your code that's causing the react hydration error: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error. ALSO: I assume you know that JS Math.Random() gives you a floating point number  >= 0.0 and less than 1.0 (not an integer): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) generate floating number. Try `Math.floor(Math.random() * <max value>)` to round them into integer.

Comment: I agree with @Mukyuu try `console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))`

Comment: Next.js pre-renders pages. That being said, this error is happening because the random number generated by `Math.random()` when pre-rendering the page on the server doesn't match the random number generated client-side when hydration occurs.

Comment: @paulsm4 That is all my code. If you create a new next app and add the code to a page, it should show the same error.

Comment: @ivanatias How can it be made to only run once?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in my comment and one of the answers, the problem is happening because Next.js pre-renders pages, therefore, the random number generated by `Math.random()` when pre-rendering the page on the server doesn't match the random number generated client-side when hydration occurs.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve by setting random ids to what seems to be "dummy data" (You could do it manually with constant values that will match both server and client-side) but I understand that this might be a simplified example.

You have a couple of options, typically you'd want to move any random generation code/logic inside a `useEffect` hook so it executes on the client-side only.

Another solution would be to move your "dummy data" and the rendering of this data to a separate component, let's call it `DummyComponent`:

```
const data = [
    {
        id: Math.random(),
        sentence: 'hello there',
    },
    {
        id: Math.random(),
        sentence: 'bye!',
    },
]

const DummyComponent = () => (
 <>
  <h1>{data[0].id}</h1>
  <h1>{data[0].sentence</h1>
  <h1>{data[1].id}</h1>
  <h1>{data[1].sentence}</h1>
 </>
)

export default DummyComponent
```

And import it dynamically on your page disabling `ssr`:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const DummyComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/DummyComponent'), {
  ssr: false,
})

export default function Index(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <DummyComponent />
    </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) npm package to generate unique id's.

```
import { v4 } from "uuid";

const data = [
    {
        id: v4(),
        sentence: 'hello there',
    },
    {
        id: v4(),
        sentence: 'bye!',
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the page is rendered on the server, then returned to the client to rehydrate, two times initializing data would cause different ID values. This is called hydration mismatch, which is solved by [`useId`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useid) in React 18

But using NextJS, you could solve this problem by initializing `data` on server to keep it consistent

```
export default function Index(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.data[0].id}</h1>
      <h1>{props.data[0].sentence}</h1>
      <h1>{props.data[1].id}</h1>
      <h1>{props.data[1].sentence}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      data: [
        {
          id: Math.random(),
          sentence: 'hello there',
        },
        {
          id: Math.random(),
          sentence: 'bye!z',
        },
      ],
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-kpwqmb?file=pages/index.js)

#### References

[getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)